# Error uploading zip files using Web services

Tags: asp.net

his is a VS 2010 windows application that calls Web Services to upload and dowload files between the local machine and a remote machine.(Please note that this application was converted from vs2008 to vs2010 to use .net 4- It worked fine before this conversion took place)

It works fine for .pdf and text files.

But when trying to upload zip files, I am getting the error

**System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---> Maximum request length exceeded. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)**

Update: I have included `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240"/>` in the web.config file
of the Web service. The zip files are larger than 8 MB

Any suggestions?

Answer:  `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="209715200"/>`

Comment: Is the client using WCF (service reference) or the "old" (web reference) approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can this section under `System.Web`

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="209715200"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The size specified is in kilobytes. The default is 4096 KB (4 MB).

Comment: But you have part of your question stackUser, how find your httpRuntime

Comment: Ok thanks. But it didn't seem to make any difference. Still getting the same error

Comment: I'am happy to help you, i suggest you to define this config file in your application, because if you don't define, you apply the configuratin of machine.config and so i think that you are limited by your machine.config on maxRequestLength

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work- Just had to change the value of maxRequestLength.